# Queue nowait in python with single producer and consumer

Tags: queue, python-3.8

I am running the code below as an example in python3.8.10, I was curious to see what happens if we don't lock the queue and there is one writer and one reader. I would have expected some corruption in case of multithreading when big data amount is read, but this doesn't seem the case, the result looks correct with or without the sleep in the code. Anyone has an idea why? It shouldn't be thread safe neither with one writer and one reader...

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import signal
import time


v1 = "hello"*10000
v2 = "good"*10000
v3 = "world"*10000


def producer(q: Queue):
    while True:
        q.put(v1, block=False)
        q.put(v2, block=False)
        q.put(v3, block=False)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        


def consumer(q: Queue):
    while True:
        try:
            val = q.get_nowait()
            print(val)
            print("\n")
        except Exception:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    p = Thread(target=producer, args=(q,), daemon=True)
    c = Thread(target=consumer, args=(q,), daemon=True)
    c.start()
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score -1):

Apparently the queue is implemented thread-safe, when block is True avoids only busy waiting

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.